# Implementing MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy prevents my site from using CSS

Tags: java, css, wicket

I developed an application in Wicket with a CSS-styled left menu. Everything worked fine. Then, to get the URLs to be RESTful, I changed `WicketApplication.java` to use `MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy`. From then on, the style stopped working. I don't know where the problem is. I didn't change anything else. Here's my code:

```
mount("/site",PackageName.forPackage(WelcomePage.class.getPackage()));
//
mount("/download",PackageName.forPackage(AppDownloadApi.class.getPackage()));

// mountBookmarkablePage("push/reg", PushRegApi.class);
   mountBookmarkablePage("push/send", PushMessageApi.class);
   mountBookmarkablePage("device", DeviceprofileExportAsXML.class);
// mountBookmarkablePage("app/download", AppDownloadApi.class);
// mountBookmarkablePage("ds/export", ExportDataSource.class);
// mountBookmarkablePage("control/export", ExportAsXML.class);

MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy ds = new MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy(
    "ds", ExportDataSource.class, new String[]{"name"});
mount(ds);

MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy control = new MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy(
    "control", ExportAsXML.class, new String[]{"controlName"});
mount(control);

MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy app = new MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy(
    "app", AppDownloadApi.class, new String[]{"appId"});
mount(app);

MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy pushReg = new MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy(
    enter code here  "push/reg", PushRegApi.class, new String[]{"appName",
    "groupName","userName","password","deviceToken"});
mount(pushReg);
```

If I uncomment the comments, and remove `MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy`, then everything works fine. How can I have both RESTful URLs and my desired style?

Comment: Are you sure that if you remove the MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy the css is working fine again? This only changes the way URL's for BookmarkablePages are built. Even if using relative paths in the css, they are relative to the css, not the current document, so I don't see why this should happen.

Comment: yeah. it works if i remove MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy and mount the packages.what's the solution for this.

Comment: Please post the CSS part that's misbehaving, the relevant HTML part and the URL's with and without the MixedParamUrlCodingStrategy.

Comment: I identified the problem. Problem is with the wicket filter configured in web.xml.Previously it was like this<url-pattern> /app/*</>.  I changed this to /*. This is causing the problem. what is the relation between url pattern and css?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with how you are linking your CSS into the pages.  We had a simmilar issue when first starting as we had hardcoded the path to CSS into the page, but then when we changed the mappings of some pages the relative paths to the CSS files were nolonger valid.

I would suggest to use FireBug and check the Net tab to see if the CSS is loading, and if so what the contents of the request returns.

You may need to use something like the CSSPackageResource.getHeaderContributer to link the css to the page correctly.